# Proving the concavity/convexity of two functions

Tags: calculus, logarithms, convex-analysis

I'll get to the point, I need to prove(in a simple way) that:

1. Prove that $f(x)=\ln(49-(x-4)^4-(6-x)^4)$ is strictly concave.

My try: Derivatives are too harsh, so I tried proving $f(x)+f(y) \leq 2f(\frac{x+y}{2})$ for every $x,y$. I tried calculating it but it gets very ugly.

2. Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $n \geq 2$, and the numbers $a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n \in (\frac{1}{n},1).$ Prove that $g(x)=(\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i+n)^x)(n-\sum_{i=1}^na_i^x)$ is strictly convex.

My try: I didn't actually know how to begin on this one since derivatives clearly aren't a good idea and I don't think we can use induction(I was thinking of proving the second derivative is positive with induction).

Comment: Derivatives don't seem that bad actually, it comes down to seeing that $f'^2-f f''<0$ where $f$ is the inside of the log. This is just a polynomial...

Comment: The coefficients are really big and the degree will be 5 I think so I don't know if it's doable. The problems are from a book(I don't have solutions) so they must have a normal/nice solution.

Comment: 1: try writing it as $\ln(g(x))$ with $g$ strictly concave

Comment: 2: try writing $g(x) = \sum_j h_j(x)$ with $h_j(x) = (a_j+n)^x(n-\sum_{i=1}^na_i^x)$ and verifying if $h_j$ is strictly convex (first via its graph, then rigorously).

Comment: I did the first one but I don't know how to prove the second one, but what you said seems true.